# Update ui-router resolved data across different states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui-router` to manage various states of my site. I have used `resolve` to pass data to `header` and `home` controller as displayed in following code. So now I need to update the value of resolved data from `HomeController` and this change should reflect across to `HeaderController` too.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"]);

myapp.service("DataService", [function() {
  var data = { title: 'Some Title' };

  this.get = function() {
    return data;
  };

}]);

myapp.controller("HeaderController", ["data", function(data) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.title = data.title;
}]);

myapp.controller("HomeController", ["data", function(data) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.title = data.title;

  vm.updateTitle = function() {

    // update the resolved data here so the header and home view 
    // updates with new data.title

    data = { title: "Another title" };

    // i know i can do vm.title = data.title; to update home view. 
    // But would be nice to globally update and reflect that change 
    // on all controllers sharing the same resolved data
  };
}]);

myapp.config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state({
        name: "root",
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            "header": {
                templateUrl: "header.html",
                controller: 'HeaderController as vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
          data: ['DataService', function(DataService) {
            return DataService.get();
          }]
        }
    })
    .state({
        name: "root.home",
        url: "",
        views: {
            "content@": {
                templateUrl: "home.html",
                controller: "HomeController as vm"
            }
        }
    })
});
```

PS: 
Before looking into `resolve`, I was injecting service directly into the controller so please do not suggest on doing that.

**EDIT**: Plunkr updated and now works as expected.

Here is link to [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p13dQfV0pxX7s2kbIiJk?p=preview)

**Lesson Learnt:**

Angular only watches the object that is assigned to the scope, and keeps separate reference of the objects. I mean:

```
data = { title: 'some title' };
vm.data = data;
vm.title = data.title;

data.title = 'another title';

{{vm.title}} // some title
```

/////////////////

```
data = { title: 'some title' };
vm.data = data;

data.title = 'another title';

{{vm.data.title}} // another title
```

Comment: try to use `setter` inside your service. What you're doing right now is just replacing a reference which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have tried using `setter` too. It wont work as expected.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CRw5EBA6BwPjy1W2mxCz?p=preview (using `$state.reload()` and changing data by reference).

Comment: @OlegMeleshko Instead of using `$state.reload()`, you can use `$watch` in the client controllers. See [this PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/UxD5V3T2GS3HZ7SkIgzH?p=preview).

Comment: @georgeawg mm, no. I'd not use `watchers` for that since it may lead to memory leakages later.

Comment: `$watch` listeners **are** destroyed when the controllers scope is destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take an advantage of the variable reference, where you should bind your `HeaderController` data to `vm.data = data`

Another incorrect thing is `data = { title: "Another title" };` which would create an data object with new reference, and the reference of service object will lost. Instead of that you should do `data.title = 'Another title';`

**header.html**

```
{{vm.data.title}}
```

**HeaderController**

```
myapp.controller("HeaderController", ["data", function(data) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = data;
}]);
```

Update updateTitle method code to below.

```
vm.updateTitle = function() {

  // update the resolved data here so the header updates with new data.title
  vm.data.title =  "Another title";
};
```

[**Demo here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/H8fqYjN8uictNH3KMhpz?p=preview)

I'd say that rather than playing with actual object reference, you should have `setTitle` function inside your factory, from `updateTitle` you will call that setter method which will update title. But in that case you need to again add the service reference on both controller. If its static data then there is no need to pass them by having resolve function. I'd loved to inject the service inside my controllers and then will play with data by its getter & setter.

Preferred Approach [**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OeFRrh4JhTZk70sxEQit?p=preview)

Comment: There is a problem on doing that. In reality the data object is quite big and has lots of functions and other object to it. Then the template would be really cluttered.

Comment: @Subash so the getter & setter approach would be better to implement, rather than passing values from the resolve function.

Comment: I used to do it that way before like I mentioned in the PS. However I updated the app to use resolve now which seems to be much cleaner.

Comment: @Subash yes..but then you need `DataService` to your controller's to calling there setters, if you want to follow that way?

Comment: Check out this plunkr.  
http://plnkr.co/edit/CRw5EBA6BwPjy1W2mxCz?p=preview That solves my issue. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: @PankajParkar suggested better solution, but thanks ;)

Comment: @Subash but that solution will reload whole state for just to updating title..wouldn't make sense for me..think if you have data on page which is doing ajax calls..so those call will happen again..now its upto you..what to follow? I you only wanted to make your code working then go for it..personally I wouldn't go for that approach . Sorry Oleg :(

Comment: I agree with you. This is quite annoying for me as its a lot of work to go back not using resolve :(

Comment: @Subash let me create a plunkr for suggested prefer answer..that would help you to fix it..

Comment: @PankajParkar I will update the plunkr to have bit more realistic scenario of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Subash did you looked at update in answer with the preferred approach?

Comment: @PankajParkar yes I did. That will make my code cluttered. I will update my plunkr to so you can visualize what I am trying to say. Give me a sec.

Comment: Okies great. Seems like getter setter approach works with `resolve` too. But the only problem is I got to update the whole object rather than just the object. But I can live with that. Please check my updated plunkr for updated code.